# Impossible Java memory references in Heap Dump

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a Java Heap Dump taken at 7:41pm which I am analysing with Eclipse Memory Analysis Tool. The heap dump includes 20 session objects.

Using the Path to GC Roots command on one of these session objects in my heap shows the following 3 references to the session object.

- A finalizer reference from the "unfinalized" linked list owned by the Finalizer thread. My object is 3rd in line to be finalized.
- A strong reference to the session object from a message handler thread which is itself referenced from a cleanup TimerTask scheduled to run at 7:11pm.
- A weak reference to the session object from a WeakHashMap$Entry. The WeakHashMap is kept alive by a static strong reference.

How can the session object be on the finalizer queue when it still has a strong and a weak reference?

Of the remaining 19 session objects, 1 more is in the finalizer queue and has a similar weak reference. All the other 18 session objects are only weakly referenced. Why hasn't the GC cleared these weak refs?

A few general points:

- Objects are only eligible for finalization AFTER their weak refs have been cleared (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html)
- The session object does not have a finalizer which could resurrect it and even if it did it couldn't have been run while the object is still in the unfinalized queue behind other objects.
- My application doesn't use Phantom refs which are the only refs which should be able to exist once an object is eligible for finalization. Even if my app did use phantom refs these objects do not expose their reference to the object they hold.

Comment: Have you actually had one of your session objects finalized while it was still reachable?  If not then I wouldn't worry about it.  Being in the queue does not necessarily mean it will be finalized while the strong and/or weak references are still live.

Comment: What mechanism would stop the objects in the finalizer queue from being finalized? The objects should not be in this queue if they are not eligible.

Comment: this is explained in [Cowan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680081/impossible-java-memory-references-in-heap-dump/4759026#4759026).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the mistake you're making here is in this part:

> A finalizer reference from the "unfinalized" linked list owned by the Finalizer thread. My object is 3rd in line to be finalized.

If you're talking about this:

```
static private Finalizer unfinalized = null;
```

in Sun's `Finalizer.java` (a `Finalizer` contains a `next` and `prev` `Finalizer`, hence the 'linked list' part, for those playing along at home), then that's not the list of things to be finalized.

`Finalizer.add()` is not (as I think you're assuming) called during the finalization process, when the object is unreachable; rather, that method is called at *creation* time of the Object (e.g. during `<init>`, by native code, for any Object which overrides `finalize()`.

The presence of a Finalizer in the `next` chain doesn't mean it's about to be finalized; it's the

```
static private ReferenceQueue queue
```

which holds such objects. Being in the linked list just means that it *has* a `finalize()` method.

Therefore your first point is a red herring, it's your second point that's keeping the item reachable, and the third point flows from the second (because the `WeakReference` won't be cleared while the object is reachable).

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's possible to resurrect objects by some other reference, even if the object itself doesn't have a faulty finalize.

Answer (score 0):

Weak references are only an indication for the GC. You have no hard guarantees when it will be cleared up.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html "Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will atomically clear all weak references to that object"

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object scheduled for finalize available again.

I know about:

> The session object does
>   not have a finalizer which could
>   resurrect it and even if it did it
>   couldn't have been run while the
>   object is still in the unfinalized
>   queue behind other objects.

However there might be other objects doing so (i.e. having ref to the Session and getting themselves rez'd). Either way show the finalizer of that Session thingie.

notes: before clearing the phantom refs the Object WILL NOT be available for finalization. (Phantom references are most often used for scheduling **pre-mortem** cleanup actions, *javadoc*), pre (not post like Weak ones).