# MAT identifying a leak in UI elements I didn't create

Tags: android, memory-leaks, eclipse-mat

I ran MAT on my application to see if I can reduce memory leaks and `OutOfMemoryException's that are happening to my users.

I saw in the histogram that was generated by the tool that one of my activities wasn't cleared from memory even though I called finish and created no cyclic references that I was aware of. so I looked through all the incoming references excluding all soft/weak references and saw that there's an `EditText` that has no name and that I haven't put in the activity.

attached is a screenshot of the report.

please help me understand how to plug this leak.

[image: MAT screenshot]

Comment: That looks like the object is about to be finalized and garbage collected. Did you force a GC before recording the memory dump?

Comment: What are you running this on? Device or emulator? OS level? The current source for `android.widget.Editor` does not show any references to `OrientationEventListener`.

Comment: @zapl - I always force GC before getting a dump.

Comment: @CommonsWare - multiple devices, multiple OS, in this case it was a SGH-T999 running the T-Mobile version of Android 4.1.2

Comment: [Memory leak through IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135931/memory-leak-through-iclipboarddatapasteeventimpl) seems relevant (and hints to a Samsung bug). The `FinalizerReference` is btw no sign of impending collection as I thought, it is created for objects that override [`finalize` upon creation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4759026/995891)

Comment: Umm can you tell me the OS build ID?

Comment: @Reno - http://pbrd.co/1hfa3sh